# Read file line by line and print if it contains two different strings

Tags: python

So I have a file called 'clears' and I want to see if a line contains two different strings that are in a list and if so to print those lines I cant get it to work.

```
for pos in positions:
    for line in open('clears'):
        if pos[0] and pos[3] in line:
            print line
```

I also tried 
f

```
or pos in positions:
        for line in open('clears'):
            if pos[0] in line and pos[3] in line:
                print line
```

Thats what I tried but I get a `TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand`
I can get it to print if there is only one condition but I am not sure how to do if there is two.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean this (EDIT, back to first version):

```
for pos in positions:
    for line in open('clears'):
        if pos[0] in line and pos[3] in line:
            print line
```

But also, the elements of `pos` must be strings.

Comment: I tried that as well earlier same error TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand

Comment: @user1440194: then the contents of your pos variable are bad